# PHP Form inside bootbox

Tags: javascript, php, forms, bootbox

I'm new in PHP and Javascript, and have a few questions, if someone can help me please.
I have this PHP form inside a bootbox, as it is in the image:
[Image of the bootbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3Rjh.png)

The code:

```
function dialogUpload() {
    bootbox.confirm({
        message:  '<form action="../Control/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> '
                + '     Nome do objeto:<br />'
                + '     <input name="objectname" type="text"><br />'
                + '     Objeto 3D(Formato <b>.dae</b>):<br />'
                + '     <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />'
                + '     Imagem 2D do objeto(Formato <b>.png</b> ou <b>.jpg</b>) (<i>Opcional</i>):'
                + '     <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />'
                + '     Comentário:<br />'
                + '     <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="75"></textarea>'
                //+ '   <input type="submit" value="Send files" />'
                + '</form>',
        buttons: {
            confirm: {
                label: 'Enviar Arquivo',
                className: 'btn-success'
            },
            cancel: {
                label: 'Cancelar',
                className: 'btn-danger'
            }
        },
        callback: function (result) {
            if(result){

            }
        }
    });
```

There are somethings I'd like to do with this form:

- Submit form using the "Enviar Botão" button(how to do it in the callback??)
- Verify if the file format is the valid format(.dae in the 1º and .png or .jpg in the 2º), and block it if it's not a valid format(showing an error message)
- Make the second file an optional input of the user

I've seen a few answers on how to check formats on PHP, but nothing else..
The tricky part is that the form is inside the bootbox window, so probably I would have to insert the code inside the `message` attribute...that's correct?

Solution to the callback:

```
<form name="uploadForm" action...>
callback: function (result) {
            if(result){
                document.uploadForm.submit();
            }
        }
```

Comment: For what it's worth, that's not really how the bootbox.confirm helper is meant to be used. What you've shown here is better suited to using the [custom dialog](http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#bb-custom-dialog)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can submit your form by adding onclick event to your button like so:
   jQuery:

   $('button.submit_button').on({
   click: function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $(this).closest('form').submit();
   }
   });
2. You can refer any file info by:

   var file = document.forms['formName']['inputName'].files[0];

see FileAPI on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

3. Use HTML5 Requered fields and check this on backend

Comment: Thanks, but in this case, The bootbox  button click already calls the callback function, so, if(button response is true), I use $(this).closest('form').submit(); but it's not working ;/

Comment: try setting the form id and submit by id.

Comment: edited the code with my solution for that, thanks for the help